# Grabbing selected area within browser as an image

Tags: javascript, plugins

For a particular project, i need (with or without a browser plugin/extension?) to be able to let the user select a desired part of a web page (any other website)  and automatically save the selected area as an image to his account on our website.

So, the logic is similar to those extensions for screen capture that you drag a rectangle on the screen and it automatically grabs the image. From thereon, as soon as the user releases the mouse button, the image should somehow be transferred to our site and be placed on his account web page.

I just dont know where to start looking for a solution and how to accomplish such a task. Can this be achieved with javascript? Or an extension is a must?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhh, this sounds like you're going to have to wait for HTML6 to be able to do this...

Comment: you could capture the dimensions drawn with the mouse, and send the URL and dimensions to a server where you would launch your own  process to capture an image of the page which you then crop to the specified dimensions. You're not going to find a javascript-only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the optimistic approach justin! :)) well, those screen capturing extensions does transfer the image to their sites for further editing. Am i wrong? But surely thats an extension.

Comment: So @evan, the "drawing the dimensions" part you mention. Can that be achieved without the user installing anything for their browsers?

Comment: @Emin what, evan is describing can be done with javascript.  -snip- I take it back... it would be easier with just plain old js

Comment: @Emin You could provide a javascript bookmarklet, or an extension, but you'll need to provide something to allow your users to activate your tool on websites you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Flash. Flash can open a browser window inside itself and the user can browse to whatever site within that window and you can keep a toolbar on top that allows them to turn on/off capturing. They never leave the flash window so they stay on your site and flash can communicate whatever they draw a rectangle over back to your server.

I'm pretty sure if I had to I could do something like that with flex, but would take me a couple weeks. Not sure, but I'm pretty doubtful that an iframe and JS could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's implementation of `<canvas>` has a method [drawWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawWindow%28%29). It has been disabled for web content for security reasons however, you need an extension to use it. Once you have the screenshot in the canvas, you can call [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement#Example%3a_Getting_the_data%3a_URL_for_a_canvas) to get image data. See for example [how Adblock Plus does it](https://hg.adblockplus.org/adblockplus/file/2a3b68888c08/chrome/content/ui/sendReport.js#l300).

Chrome has a comparable API for extensions: [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab). Here you cannot choose which part of the page you want but you can still draw the resulting image into a canvas and then slice and dice it as you want.